# Selenium dotnet Signed Assembly location?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Selenium DOTNET signed assemblies?**

Was wondering if Selenium downloads already have signed assemblies?  I need them to integrate within another 3rd party application requiring strong types assemblies.

I though I had seen a list in Google Code with all of the archives but can't seem to find it... I get redirected to Github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Jim Evans, they are located here:  (Including Signed Assemblies)

http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html